# JMETER recording is not capturing mobile applications

Tags: testing, jmeter

I'm using the Android 13 version. I tried to set up a JMETER proxy on my mobile.

For that, I have all the below details to my mobile wifi settings.

- Same port number as JMETER GUI. Tried with different port numbers as well like 8080, 8181, 8888
- Installed latest JMETER certification to my mobile phone
- port
- proxy
- hostname
  Also, disabled firewall from laptop. DID RESTARTING JMETER, and mobile device.

But after I started recording from JMETER, nothing was recorded. I tried to open the chrome browser on my mobile phone and searched for 'google'. But nothing has been captured in the JMETER > recording controller / view results tree.

"No internet connection" is showing in the mobile browser after connecting with the proxy. None of the applications are connected to the internet. Even in mobile WI-FI, it shows as ""connected to the device. can't provide internet".

Also I didn't receive the notification in my mobile as "network is monitored".

Please help on how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to capture HTTPS traffic from Android device with JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder you need to amend your application's [network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config)

1. Add the next line to the [application](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element) section of your app's [manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro)

   ```
   android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
   ```
2. Create `network_security_config.xml` file in your app
   s [resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources) directory and put the below code there:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <network-security-config>
       <debug-overrides>
           <trust-anchors>
               <!-- Trust user added CAs while debuggable only -->
               <certificates src="user"/>
           </trust-anchors>
       </debug-overrides>
   </network-security-config>
   ```
3. Build your application in [debug mode](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#DebugMode)
4. Replace the existing application with the debug one from step 3
5. You should be able to record now

See [Configure Android Devices for Proxy Recording](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354685999889-Configure-Android-Devices-for-Proxy-Recording) guide for more details

Another possible reasons for recording failures:

- Your application uses other protocol(s) than HTTP(S). In this case you need to use operating-system-wide sniffer tool to capture its traffic in "raw" mode. Then you need to analyze the traffic and choose appropriate [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) or [Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) which can simulate the app's network footprint
- You're behind a corporate proxy/firewall. In this case you will need to [make JMeter aware of this upstream proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server).

Comment: One doubt here @Dmitri T , none of the applications are working even device chrome browser. It's also, because of the same above mentioned reason you mean?